# How to make gulp-git pause until the git command finishes?

Tags: git, gulp

I've been tearing my hair out over this for two hours.

Here is my simplified gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var run_sequence = require("run-sequence");
var del = require("del");
var git = require("gulp-git");
var wait = require("gulp-wait");

var dest = 'build/';

var vendor_javascript_files = [
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
];

var app_javascript_files = [
    'app.js',
];

// Remove the existing build directory
gulp.task("prepare",function() {
    return del([dest, "branding_assets/"]);
});

gulp.task("get-branding", function() {
    return git.clone('http://gitserver.local/prod-branding.git', {args: './branding_assets'}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
        throw err;
        }
    });
});

gulp.task("get-dev-branding", function() {
    return git.clone('http://gitserver.local/dev-branding.git', {args: './branding_assets'}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
        throw err;
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('vendor-js', function() {
    return gulp.src(vendor_javascript_files)
        .pipe(concat("vendor.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest+"app"));
});

gulp.task('app-files', function() {
    return gulp.src(['app.js'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest+"app"));
});

gulp.task('branding', function() {
    return gulp.src('branding_assets/*')
        .pipe(wait(2000))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest+"assets"))
});

gulp.task('app-js', function() {
    return gulp.src("index.html.dist")
        .pipe(rename("index.html"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});

gulp.task('build', function() {
    run_sequence(
        "prepare",
        "get-branding",
        [
            "app-files",
            "app-js",
            "vendor-js",
            // imagine there are many more tasks here - "app-css", "vendor-css", "app-sass", etc. Upwards of 10 tasks.
            "branding",
        ],
    );
});

gulp.task('build-dev', function() {
    run_sequence(
        "prepare",
        "get-dev-branding",
        [
            "app-files",
            "app-js",
            "vendor-js",
            // imagine there are many more tasks here - "app-css", "vendor-css", "app-sass", etc. Upwards of 10 tasks.
            "branding",
        ],
    );
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

What I am trying to do is, during the gulp task, pull in the assets for the respective project version and then use them in the build process.

The problem is that the `gulp.clone` task returns immediately, before the clone has completed. Thus, the `branding` task does nothing since the files don't yet exist when it starts.

I tried using the `.wait(2000)` to pause the branding task, but 1) that doesn't actually work (it still finishes the branding task in tens of ms) and 2) it wouldn't work even if the pause did occur because the source files are selected at the time the `src` function runs, right?

Maybe `gulp` isn't an appropriate task runner for my task, but I have no choice - production environment uses gulp.

Using the `get-branding` task as a dependency on each of the individual build tasks (e.g. "app-files") won't work since sometimes we want to run `get-dev-branding` instead. I even tried doing a "nesting" strategy of moving all the individual app build tasks into separate tasks with `get-branding` as a dependency and it still did not work - since the `git.clone` task always returns immediately before the clone has finished, it doesn't work.

I can't find anything that would, say, "wait until this file exists". I can't find anything to reliably pause a gulp task before it starts enumerating its source files. I'm going in circles on google hitting the same pages over and over with no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a callback to your function, so you can pass the callback status of the command back to gulp.

```
gulp.task("get-branding", function(done) {
    git.clone('http://gitserver.local/prod-branding.git', {args: './branding_assets'}, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            done(err);
        }
        done();
    });
});
```

For more information about how this done callback function works internally, you can see: [gulp: where is the gulp task callback function defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298244/gulp-where-is-the-gulp-task-callback-function-defined)

> The callback function comes from Orchestrator (or the new one --
>   undertaker -- in Gulp 4) and is actually nothing more than a call to
>   tell the task system that your task is "done". That's why they changed
>   it to
>
> ```
> gulp.task('something', function(done) { ... });
> ```
>
> In the upcoming docs to make that point clearer.

Comment: Oh my god, it worked... thank you!!! You just saved my scalp from many more parted hairs. :-)